# How to add a navigation bar and a backbutton in it in my xCode 4 application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation

I have a simple app with 3 tab items and a view for each of them. How can I add a nav bar which shows only the name of the current view, and a backbutton to appear when I go to another page, and not in the first one which shows when I open my app?

Comment: You have mistaken it, my friend. This this a Q&A site. Not Interactive Tutorials.

Comment: It sounds like you are using a tab-based application, and then getting a navigation bar added to each page separately. After doing that for a month, I decided to pull out the tab controller and use sliding-menus plus a navigation bar, and I am so delighted to get back all the space on the bottom of my main view where the tab controller use to be. Just an idea... Why put 3 tabs plus 3 navigation controllers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a `UINavigationController` as the root for each of your tabs, with the existing view controllers each set as the respective navigation controller's root view controller.

See the View Controller Programming Guide for more details: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html